# Does passing a function belonging to self cause a retain cycle when not in a closure?

Tags: swift, memory-management, functional-programming, swift2, retain-cycle

If you need to reference `self` inside of a closure, it's good practice to pass it in as `weak` or `unowned` to prevent a retain cycle.

If I pass the function that belongs to `self` directly, will it cause a retain cycle? Or does it need to be nested inside a closure to weakify self?

**Passing directly**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3,
        delay: 0.0,
        usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7,
        initialSpringVelocity: 0.1,
        options: .CurveEaseOut,
        animations: self.view.layoutIfNeeded, // does this cause retain cycle? 
        completion: nil)
```

**Wrapping in a closure**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3,
        delay: 0.0,
        usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7,
        initialSpringVelocity: 0.1,
        options: .CurveEaseOut,
        animations: { [unowned self] in
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        },
        completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should not create a reference cycle, but even if it did that would be ok. The reference cycle would only exist until the animation completed, at which point it would be broken. Creating short-lived reference cycles can actually be beneficial because it ensures that the target continues to exist for the life of the call. Cycles are not inherently a problem. *Unbreakable* cycles are the problem.

There are two reasons that this doesn't create a cycle. First, there is no "cycle." The system is going to reference *something* (more on that in a second), sure. But where's the reference to "the thing that is referencing that something?" To say it a bit more clearly, even if the animation system referenced `self`, how is `self` referencing the animation system? There is no cycle.

The other reason there is no cycle is that you're not passing `self` to animation system anyway. Your passing `self.view.layoutIfNeeded`. In Swift, that's equivalent to:

```
UIView.layoutIfNeeded(self.view)
```

You're not passing `self` here. You're passing a view. Now the animation system almost certainly *will* hold a reference to that view until the animation completes, but that's fine. That's still not  a cycle.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reference cycle since `self` doesn't capture the closure but if you don't want that there is another strong reference to `self` you can use the wrapping closure.

If you are sure that `self` is not deallocated in the next 0.3 seconds you can use `unowned` otherwise `weak`. (I would use `weak` just to be sure it doesn't crash)